# Check for readyState in an Ember app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have an iframe in my template as below;

```
<iframe id="iframeContainer" src="javascript:;"></iframe>
```

In the corresponding route, I want some form to be appended dynamically. I want it to work in IE, Firefox & Chrome. However the code inside readyState is not triggered at all. Not sure if I am not adding the check in the correct place ?

```
didTransition: function() {
    var self = this;
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
        document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
            if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
                var iframeContainer = document.getElementById('iframeContainer');
                var innerDoc = (iframeContainer.contentDocument) ? iframeContainer.contentDocument : iframeContainer.contentWindow.document;
                innerDoc.body.innerHTML += '<form id="myForm"></form>';
                innerDoc.getElementById("myForm").submit();
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Why do you need addEventListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
didTransition: function() {
var self = this;
Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
        if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
            var iframeContainer = document.getElementById('iframeContainer');
            var innerDoc = (iframeContainer.contentDocument) ? iframeContainer.contentDocument : iframeContainer.contentWindow.document;
            innerDoc.body.innerHTML += '<form id="myForm"></form>';
            innerDoc.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
})
```

}

The event listener never triggers if are you going to use didTransation it will take care that when you come on this route form will be added.

Comment: Thx a lot. Works perfectly in Chrome. In IE, I am getting some error in displaying the iframe. Not sure if that might be something to do with cross-domain (testing on localhost URL)

This page can’t be displayed
•Make sure the web address //ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff.htm# is correct.